# Next.js route rendering issue

Tags: next.js

I am seeing the following error with next.js routing for **non-hash routes** (I know comments on other similar issues claimed that the cause of this issue was adding a hash to the query).

```
Error: Cancel rendering route
```

Has anyone seen this before, know what it means, and how to fix it? It seems to only be happening on Safari and mobile Chrome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing this too, only on desktop Safari and mobile Safari/Chrome (webview). Using our logs, we were able to notice that this happens e.g. when a user was browsing the Next.js app, then did nothing for ~1 hour, then started browsing again. So this smells like some issue with how Safari/Mobile Safari backgrounds unused tabs and then un-backgrounds them.

I wonder if there is some sort of fix that the Next.js folks can do, since it seems to be at the framework level.